# Publish all network posts to the primary site

Tags: multisite

Any posts published on another network site should be visible on the MainDomain.com.  Sitetags works fine, but does not update itself.  Any idea how how to make an auto update on the primary site?

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 1):

Use ThreeWP_Broadcast. It's a great plugin for doing that.

Comment: Any idea on the error?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in

Comment: Does the error give you a file for where it's occurring?

Comment: ywp-content/plugins/threewp-broadcast/ThreeWP_Broadcast.php on line 17

Comment: Fixed the error, but its not broadcasting

Comment: Have you checked the settings page, and also told it to broadcast from the post edit screen? I've been using this plugin for months and have never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Post Indexer](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/post-indexer). I'm using it [here](http://blogs.colman.ac.il/all/) (see tag cloud)

Comment: Looking for a free plugin